# Bit Synchronization (in Physical Layer) vs Flow Control (in Data Link Layer) - What's the difference?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Let's say a server has 1 Gbps upload speed, and a client has 100 Mbps download speed.

Client requests data from this server and the server starts to send.

To prevent frames being lost, there should be a data rate synchronization.

In OSI model, doesn't **Physical Layer** do that with **Bit Synchronization**?

But also we have **Flow Control** in **Data Link Layer**, and as I know it's for the same reason. For data rate synchronization **to prevent frames being lost**.

If it works like this, according to OSI model there are 2 times synchronization. First physical layer, then data link layer and why would it work like that?

There should be a difference between **Physical Layer's Bit Synchronization** and **Data Link Layer's Flow Control**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clarified the question. All the details here.

Comment: @rch, ask for **SPECIFIC** problem. Currently it is too generic.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I added very specific case.

Comment: I believe you're mixing up things a) the speed at which communications is done needs to be negotiated before anything else can happen, same speed from both ends dependent on capabilities, b) the hardware level synchronization is one thing, protocol "synchronization" something totally different...; recommended start point for reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer - you may need to find explanations to technical terms mentioned in there.

Comment: Information about the subject is freely available and easy to find. Please study the documentation before asking questions.

Comment: Primary job of flow control is to prevent buffer overrun at the receiving end. When the receiving end doesn't have available memory to retain the latest frame as it arrives, then that data is discarded (despite a successful transfer over the physical link). Flow control is implemented to prevent such situations. So there is a clear "*difference between **Physical Layer's Bit Synchronization** and **Data Link Layer's Flow Control**.*"

Comment: @harrymc I've already studied and I'm confused that's why I am asking this. To learn.

Comment: And much appreciate @sawdust for your comment, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to answer...

1. Physical level synchronization
   Here we make sure to be able to send any data at all, how to send to make it readable in the receiving end.
2. Flow control
   a) e.g. at which rate can the receiving end interpret and act on the data that the sending end might be able to produce. Or
   b) the other way around; at which rate can requests (from a master) be responded to by a device (slave) with limited processing power.